# Dropdown not showing after sidebar selection

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

In my rails 5.1.1 app, I have 3 (for now) identical pages, [containing each 3 dropdown menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DJ4l.jpg) used to render a specific partial according to the selected option. (using jquery change() ) . It all works well, but the problem is that if I use the sidebar to go from one page to the oder, [the dropdown menu is not shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiwDy.jpg) and I have to manually refresh the page to get is to show. If I go to the page by typing the URL everything appears as it should. Any idea why?

here is the "/policy" page with the dropdowns (the code is probably a little messy since I've just started with web developement):

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="height: 90rem;" >
  <div class="row"><h1 class="page-header" style="color: #777777">Privacy settings<small> <br>Here is a list of the available privacy settings on different social networks. Click on a setting to see its details </small></h1><br>


  </div>

  <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 3rem;text-align: center"> <!-- selection row -->

    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 dropsel"> <!-- first column -->

      <select id="selectMe2" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" title="Choose social network" >
        <option>None</option>
        <option value="facebook2">Facebook</option>
        <option value="twitter2">Twitter</option>
        <option value="linkedin2">LinkedIn</option>
        <option value="google2">Google +</option>
        <option value="pinterest2">Pinterest</option>
      </select>
    </div>

      <div class="col-md-3 dropsel" > <!-- second column -->

        <select id="selectMe3" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" title="Choose social network">
          <option>None</option>
          <option value="facebook3">Facebook</option>
          <option value="twitter3">Twitter</option>
          <option value="linkedin3">LinkedIn</option>
          <option value="google3">Google +</option>
          <option value="pinterest3">Pinterest</option>
        </select>

      </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 dropsel" > <!-- third column -->

          <select id="selectMe4" class="selectpicker" data-width="fit" title="Choose social network">
            <option>None</option>
            <option value="facebook4">Facebook</option>
            <option value="twitter4">Twitter</option>
            <option value="linkedin4">LinkedIn</option>
            <option value="google4">Google +</option>
            <option value="pinterest4">Pinterest</option>
          </select>

        </div>
  </div>


<div class="row"> <!-- content row  -->
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1 dropcont"> <!-- first content column -->


      <div id="facebook2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"fbpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="twitter2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"twpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="linkedin2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"lkpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="google2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"googlepartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="pinterest2" class="group2" >
        <%= render partial:"pinpartial" %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /first column -->


  <div class="col-md-3 dropcont"> <!-- second content column -->

      <div id="facebook3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"fbpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="twitter3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"twpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="linkedin3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"lkpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="google3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"googlepartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="pinterest3" class="group3" >
        <%= render partial:"pinpartial" %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /second column -->

  <div class="col-md-3 dropcont"> <!-- third content column -->

      <div id="facebook4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"fbpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="twitter4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"twpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="linkedin4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"lkpartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="google4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"googlepartial" %>
      </div>

      <div id="pinterest4" class="group4" >
        <%= render partial:"pinpartial" %>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /third column -->



  </div>
</div>

<!-- scripts -->

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.group2').hide();//hide
        //set default class to be shown here, or remove to hide all
                $('#selectMe2').change(function () {//on change do stuff
            $('.group2').hide();//hide all with .group2 class
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); //show selected option's respective element
        })
    });</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.group3').hide();//hide
        //set default class to be shown here, or remove to hide all
        $('#selectMe3').change(function () {//on change do stuff
            $('.group3').hide();//hide all with .group2 class
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); //show selected option's respective element
        })
    });</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.group4').hide();//hide
        //set default class to be shown here, or remove to hide all
        $('#selectMe4').change(function () {//on change do stuff
            $('.group4').hide();//hide all with .group2 class
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show(); //show selected option's respective element
        })
    });</script>
```

and here is the relevant part of the layout containing the sidebar ("public", "policy" and "privacy_setting" pages are identical for the moment:

```
[<div id="wrapper" class="toggled" style="background-color: whitesmoke; ">

  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" style="width: 22rem; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <div class="profile-sidebar">
      <!-- SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
      <div class="profile-userpic">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400/people/1" class="img-responsive" alt="">
      </div>
      <!-- END SIDEBAR USERPIC -->
      <!-- SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
      <div class="profile-usertitle">
        <div class="profile-usertitle-name">
          Sandra Monty
        </div>
        <div class="profile-usertitle-job">
          Welcome
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END SIDEBAR USER TITLE -->
      <!-- SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
      <div class="profile-userbuttons">

      </div>
      <!-- END SIDEBAR BUTTONS -->
      <!-- SIDEBAR MENU -->
      <div class="profile-usermenu">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="<%= 'active' if params\[:controller\] == 'privacy_setting' %>">
            <a href="privacy_setting">
              <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Privacy Settings </a>
          </li>
          <li class="<%= 'active' if params\[:controller\] == 'policy' %>">
            <a href="policy">
              <i class="fa fa-user-secret" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Privacy Policy </a>
          </li>
          <li class="<%= 'active' if params\[:controller\] == 'public' %>">
            <a href="public">
              <i class="fa fa-globe" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              Public information </a>
          </li>

          <li class="<%= 'active' if params\[:controller\] == 'about' %>">
            <a href="about">
              <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              About  </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- END MENU -->
      <div class=" row bottom-buttons">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings">
          <i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="FullScreen">
          <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Logout">
          <i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="force-to-bottom">
        <h5> Privacy Dashboard Prototype</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->

  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper" style="background-color: whitesmoke">

          <%= yield %>

  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->]
```

Comment: Can you show the jquery code? The issue could be there.

Comment: The one i used for the dropdown It's at the end of the first page of code

Comment: The issue could be caused by turbolinks. I'll add an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue could be caused by Turbolinks which is loaded by Rails by default. It speeds up rendering pages by using AJAX but it can mess up your JavaScript by not executing it unless you refresh the page. Wrap each of your JavaScript functions with an event listener for a turbolinks load and that may fix your issue.

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  ...your jQuery/javascript goes here...
});
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't seem to work, the dropdowns are still not rendered

Comment: But you were right about Turbolinks: now I removed them completely from my app and it works like a charm, thanks!